# javascript to show vertical scrollbar in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down list with few options in it. When user clicks on the drop down list, it has to display first four items and a vertical scroll bar. When user scrolls remainings items in the list 
are seen.

Please find the sample fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/db8Lp/105/

Please suggest how can i achieve vertical scrollbar using javascript/css to view remaining items in the list. As i am a newbie any suggestions would be very helpful.
I tried using `size="4"` in `<select>` but that displays the list with scrollbar when the page loads, but my requirement is to show the list with scrollbar when user clicks on the drop down list. Please advice.

Comment: can you use css?  give outer container a `height` value and scroll `auto`.

Comment: Open to a solution using jquery? http://jsfiddle.net/db8Lp/106/

Comment: @DaniP - I cannot use jquery, can we achieve this using javascript ?

Comment: I can use javascript, css.Can you please modify the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/db8Lp/105/ . As I tried giving height but I want to show first four options in the list with scroll bar. If I give height I think I need to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy to solve and you can do it using only html and css.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/db8Lp/110/).

In your html, you should add...

```
<select size="4">
```

In your css, you should add...

```
select {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Scroobar is not displayed. I want to show 4 items and a scroll bar too when user clicks on the list.

Comment: The OP wants: Only when the user clicks on the select tag, display the list with the scrollbar.

Comment: @YashJain - I want to show the list with scroll bar only when user clicks on the dropdown list.

Comment: So do javascript supports the functionality I asked above, please suggest.